# javascript drop down items don't appear but can be selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using dependent drop down list using PHP and JQuery. When I select one item from the first list, the second list is updated but the items don't appear. The items in the second list could be selected  Here is the photo show how i can select item but not appears.
[image]

and I made alert to show the selected item to be sure that the item index is true. Here is the photo of the alert with the name of the course

[image]
 So how can I make the items appear? here is the first page code:

```
    <div class="styled-select green semi-square">
<select name="per" id="per" onchange="getfirst(this.value);">
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <?php
    foreach($Names as $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $name ?>"><?= $name ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="styled-select green semi-square">
<select name="per1" id="per1" onchange="getsecond(this.value);" >
<option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <option value=""></option>
</select> 
</div>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script >
function getfirst(val){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getdata.php",
        data:"cid="+val,
        success:function(data){
            $("#per1").html(data);
        }
    });
}
function getsecond(val1){
    alert(val1);
}
</script>
```

And here is the code when the first item is selected (getdata.php):

```
   <?php
 require "init.php";
 global $con;

 if(!empty($_POST["cid"])){
        $query="Select * From subjects";
        $results = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        foreach($results as $value){

            ?>
            <option class="styled-select" value="<?php echo $value["Name"];?>"></option>
            <?php
        }
 }
 else 
     echo "Error";
?>
```

and here is the Css style for the drop down styles:

```
.styled-select {
   background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
   height: 29px;
   overflow: hidden;
     width: 240px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     text-align-last:center;


}
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   color:black;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 29px;
   padding: 5px; /* If you add too much padding here, the options won't show in IE */
   width: 268px;
}
.semi-square {
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

/* -------------------- Colors: Background */
.slate   { background-color: #ddd; }
.green   { background-color: #09C66E; }
.blue    { background-color: #3b8ec2; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return only a value in the option, but no text to go with it.

I took the liberty of cleaning the code a bit, so it's more readable in the future.

```
 if(!empty($_POST["cid"])){
     $query="Select * From subjects";
     $results = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     foreach($results as $value){
         $name = $value["Name"];
         $item = '<option class="styled-select" value="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';
         echo $item;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your option list has only value defined that is why you can select the value but there is not text there. I think you should use something like this.

```
<option class="styled-select" value="<?php echo $value["Name"];?>"><?php echo $value["Name"];?></option>
```

Hope this helps